# Add python set to a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

I just recently started learning Python and i already ran into something that doesn't makes sense to me.

I'm trying to make a set and then add that set to a dictionary so that i end up with something like this

```
{0: set([1,1,1,1])
 1: set([1,1,1,1])
 2: set([1,1,1,1])}
```

I have code like below:

```
my_graph = {}
my_set = set()
for i in range(0,4):
    for j in range(0,4):
        my_set.add(1)
    print my_set
    my_graph[i] = my_set
    my_set.clear()
```

The problem is that i end up with just set([1]) as a result

output:

```
set([1])
set([1])
set([1])
set([1])
```

Comment: are you thinking of a `tuple` instead ?

Comment: Also surprised how your output supposedly has 5 rows with `i` being `range(0, 4)`

Comment: sorry that was me manually changing things before posting, I'll remove the extra one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set doesn't have duplicates. Hence a set with multiple `1` elements doesn't exist. You can also see that when you compare them:

```
>>> set([1,1,1,1]) == set([1])
True
```

Comment: Thanks, beginners mistake on my part

Answer (score 0):

A set contains unique elements.
So once you add 1 to your set, you can't 1 again to your set.
Basically set([1,1,1,1]) is equal to set([1])
Just use a list, don't make it into a set.